# Facebook Android SDK default audience on open new session

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I have a problem, I saw several posts but I can't find a solution.

Im using facebook android sdk 3.5.2 and Im creating a new session using these lines:

```
    OpenRequest request = new Session.OpenRequest(this).setDefaultAudience(SessionDefaultAudience.FRIENDS);
    session.openForPublish(request.setCallback(callback).setPermissions("email", "publish_actions"));
```

But the default audience is not working, I just get "Only Me", so what's the way to get friend audience when I create the session?

Thanks for any help

Comment: I think, due to emial, just searching something else,